# hello. i have online assignment on Data Structure. i have tried solving these but really cant make the programs run

Tags: codeblocks

Set #1:
    Write a program that reads a series of phone numbers from a file and displays them in a standard format. Each line of the file will contain a single phone number, but the numbers may be in a variety of formats. You may assume that each line contains 10 digits, possibly mixed with  other characters (which should be ignored). For example, suppose that the file contains the following lines:

```
404.817.6900
(215) 686-1776
312-746-6000
877 275 5273
6173434200
```

The output of the program should have the following appearance:

```
(404) 817-6900
(215) 686-1776
(312) 746-6000
(877) 275-5273
(617) 343-4200
```

Set #2:
    Write a program that identifies and prints all whole numbers and real numbers from a file. The program should print first the list of whole numbers followed by the list of real numbers. 
PS. I use C language

Comment: Are there any complexity or Big-O requirements?

Comment: it's ok to ask homework related questions as long as you don't ask us to solve your problems for you. show what you've done so-far and then ask specific questions where you're stuck. welcome to stack overflow, recommended reading [ask]

Answer (score 0):

`SET1:` I mean you can read each line and only store the numbers into an array using regex or int check on each character in that line. You can then print out the whole numbers after that. From there you would need to write a function to output the contents of the array to the right format... this is simple using string concatenation with the separate array positions that correlate to a phone number.

`SET2:` Again use a function using regex or a built in function to create two arrays, one for whole numbers and the other for real numbers.